# Help with tool(s) for making a schematic from an existing board

Tags: electronics

I want to make a schematic for a a not-too-big circuit on a two-sided circuit board (see https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/388633/autopilot-gradual-failure-help-me-guess-what-might-be-going-on#388664) for pictures); the parts are all full-size (think 1988) rather than surface-mount, so they're not hard to see. There are about 40 resistors/caps/diodes, 3 ICs, a couple of trim-pots.

I can take photos of both sides of the board, make a list of parts, etc., as a starting point.

Can someone suggest tools for actually creating a schematic, where the first draft will be pretty similar to the board-layout, and I'd like to modify and move things around without losing the topology of the circuit, until it eventually becomes a logically laid-out diagram that others can perhaps help me with? I just have no idea what circuit drawing/editing tools are out there for a basic task like this.

OS: Any of Mac, Windows, Linux, Android

Price: I'm at best a hobbyist, so no more than $20.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post and include what OS the tool must run on, and what your price limit is if it comes to paid solutions?

Answer (score 1):

KiCad is free and much-loved amongst hobbyists and professionals.  It contains programs for schematic capture and PCB layout, along with other handy tools.

https://www.kicad.org/

Comment: Considering it started as an in-house project at CERN to fulfill their engineering needs, I'd argue it's loved more by scientists and professionals than by hobbyists...

Comment: @MarcusMüller I have to agree, fix'd!